# What are the Correlations for the Super-compressability Z factor?

Tags: ideal-gas

I am studying the course TPG4145 Reservoir fluids in NTNU and specifically the supercompressability factor $Z=\frac{V_{\text{real volume of the system}}}{V_{\text{ideal volume of the system}}}$ for which I try to understand the so-called correlations:

> 1. Is this word correlation really a mathematical correlation or is it just a jargon?
> 2. If the gas deviation factor $Z$ is not measured, it can be estimated from correlations ([source](http://petrowiki.org/Real_gases)) -- Phase Behaviour book by Curtis on pages 18-24. Please explain cases where the volume of the system cannot be measured and the correlations must be used or better used over some estimated volume for the system.

**Example 1.** about some reservoir

> The reservoir volume cannot be calculated because drainage (area) or net pay (thickness) cannot be calculated.
>
> > *Subproblem: How do the correlation values after calculating pseudocritical values $T_{pc}$& $P_{pc}$ and pseudoreduced values $T_p$& $P_p$ help here? We still have no idea about the drainage or the net pay.*

Comment: I want labels something like `compressability`, `z-factor`, `gas-deviation-factor` -- I could not find any label and I cannot yet create any label.

Answer (score 0):

This is a key sentence (p.24 [1]):

> *"Pseudocritical properties of gases can be estimated with **gas composition** and mixing rules or from **correlations based on gas specific gravity**."* (I added bolding)

so the supercompressability $Z$ factor (also called the deviation factor) can be defined by the following methods below.

**Method 1: gas composition values $y_i$**

> Kay's mixing rule is *"usually adequate for [clean] natural gases that contain no nonhydrocarbons"* (p.25, fixed a spelling mistake).
>
> **Kay’s mixing rule**
>
> > $T_{pc}=\sum_{i=1}^N y_i T_{ci}$
> >
> > $p_{pc}=\sum_{i=1}^N y_ip_{ci}$
> >
> > where
> >
> > [image]
> >
> > and more [here](http://petrowiki.org/Real_gases).

**Method 2: correlations**

> The Correlation -- now only Sutton and Standing in consideration -- is a function $f(\gamma_{gHC})$ where the specific gravity for gas is $\gamma_{gHC}=\frac{(\rho_g)_{sc}}{(\rho_{air})_{sc}}=\frac{M_g}{M_{air}}=\frac{M_g}{28.97}$ (p.22 [1]).
>
> **Sutton correlations (p.24 [1])**
>
> > $T_{pcHC}=169.2+349.5\gamma_{gHC}-74.0\gamma^2_{gHC}$
> >
> > $p_{pcHC}=756.8-131\gamma_{gHC}-3.6\gamma^2_{gHC}$
>
> **Standing correlations (p.24 [1])**
>
> > $T_{pcHC}=168+325\gamma_{gHC}-12.5\gamma^2_{gHC}$
> >
> > $p_{pcHC}=706-51.7\gamma_{gHC}-11.1\gamma^2_{gHC}$

**Summary**

> So the correlation method still requires the specific gravity which requires the molar mass of the gas by $\gamma_{gHC}=\frac{(\rho_g)_{sc}}{(\rho_{air})_{sc}}=\frac{M_g}{M_{air}}=\frac{M_g}{28.97}$. It sounds unbelievable that this is true: specific gravity $SG=\frac{\rho_{\text{measured substance}}}{\rho_{\text{reference substance}}}$ contains only density information and it is used for the compressability determination alone. There is no physical analysis about the repulsive forces and the attraction forces.

**Answers to the questions**

> *I. Is this word correlation really a mathematical correlation or is it just a jargon?*
>
> > It is just a model. There may be some regression/residual analysis behind how the authors have determined the correlations to make the word "correlation" justified usage.
>
> *II. Please explain cases where the volume of the system cannot be measured and the correlations must be used or better used over some estimated volume for the system.*
>
> > The Correlations offer an indirect method to estimate the Z-factor by the specific gravity $SG$ which requires only density information: nothing about the volume of the reservoir per se. It is just a method among other methods to estimate the $Z$.

**References**

> [1] Phase Behaviour, Curtis et. al 2000